# Qiskit: How to implement a classical function?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I'm quite lost, I have to implement the following function with qiskit
$$
f(x,y,z) = (\lnot x \land y \land z) \lor (x \land \lnot y \land z)
$$
but how can we do that ? I don't understand how to do the mapping between classical gates (OR, AND, XOR...) and quantum gates (CNOT, H, X...)

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [classical function compiler](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/classicalfunction.html) to build a boolean function and synthesize a quantum circuit object from that function. For example, using your boolean logic function there you could do:

```
from qiskit.circuit import classical_function, Int1

@classical_function
def my_function(x: Int1, y: Int1, z: Int1) -> Int1:
    return (not x and y and z) or (x and not y and z)
```

which will define your boolean function. Then you can synthesize a circuit from it with:

```
qc = my_function.synth()
```

if you draw `qc` you'll get:

```
print(qc)

q_0: ──■───────
       │       
q_1: ──┼────■──
       │    │  
q_2: ──■────■──
     ┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐
q_3: ┤ X ├┤ X ├
     └───┘└───┘
```

If you want to see what that looks like as just 1 and 2 qubit gates (instead of toffolis) you can decompose it and draw it which will yield:

```
print(qc.decompose())
                                                       ┌───┐                                                              
q_0: ───────────────────■─────────────────────■────■───┤ T ├───■──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                        │                     │    │   └───┘   │                                               ┌───┐      
q_1: ───────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────┼───────────┼────────────────■─────────────────────■────■───┤ T ├───■──
                        │             ┌───┐   │  ┌─┴─┐┌─────┐┌─┴─┐              │             ┌───┐   │  ┌─┴─┐┌┴───┴┐┌─┴─┐
q_2: ───────■───────────┼─────────■───┤ T ├───┼──┤ X ├┤ Tdg ├┤ X ├──■───────────┼─────────■───┤ T ├───┼──┤ X ├┤ Tdg ├┤ X ├
     ┌───┐┌─┴─┐┌─────┐┌─┴─┐┌───┐┌─┴─┐┌┴───┴┐┌─┴─┐├───┤└┬───┬┘├───┤┌─┴─┐┌─────┐┌─┴─┐┌───┐┌─┴─┐┌┴───┴┐┌─┴─┐├───┤└┬───┬┘└───┘
q_3: ┤ H ├┤ X ├┤ Tdg ├┤ X ├┤ T ├┤ X ├┤ Tdg ├┤ X ├┤ T ├─┤ H ├─┤ H ├┤ X ├┤ Tdg ├┤ X ├┤ T ├┤ X ├┤ Tdg ├┤ X ├┤ T ├─┤ H ├──────
     └───┘└───┘└─────┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└─────┘└───┘└───┘ └───┘ └───┘└───┘└─────┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└─────┘└───┘└───┘ └───┘
```

Comment: Ahh, that's nice. Does Qiskit's code just convert the classical circuit to compute that function into a reversible one?

Comment: I assume that the output is always stored in the bottom-most qubit?  (In this case `q_3`)? 

If you look at this page https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/classicalfunction.html, the sentence "The resulting..." is cut off.